# WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I've been trying to install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS having a lamp installed, php 7.2, mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2 and apache2.

and I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) article from digitalOcean, but when I came to the part that I need to run `sudo phpenmod mcrypt` I got a message saying..

WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available

I am doing this on ubuntu installed in godaddy

Can you give best solution for this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/arzzen/1209aa4a430bd95db3090a3399e6c35f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try and run this code and your error should be gone.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/
```

You should have the `mcrypt.ini` file inside `mods-available` and if you don't have this file there you will get this error.

**NOTE**: If you do it this way you will not get this error anymore, but you will get other error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

**So, based on my research `mcrypt` is not supported in php7.2, so you don't have to execute `sudo phpenmod mcrypt` at all. Maybe I am wrong, but if someone have more information, let me know.**

Answer (score 7):

First install php7.1. Then copy mcrpyt.ini.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```